# How to mutate a date given an specific date format in the same pipeline?

Tags: r, class, date

I am trying to convert a character class column to a date class.

The original character class format is `%d/%m/%Y` which I am trying to convert to date class preserving the same format.

Here's my attempt:

```
library(dplyr)

testing_df <- data.frame(mes=c('01/02/2021', 
                                '01/01/2021', '01/12/2020', 
                                '01/11/2020', '01/10/2020'))

test_pipeline <- testing_df %>%
            dplyr::filter(mes %in% c('01/02/2021', 
                              '01/01/2021', '01/12/2020', 
                              '01/11/2020', '01/10/2020')) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(mes=format(as.Date(mes, format='%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Which returns a column composed of `NA`.

The idea is that `class(test_pipeline$mes)` returns `Date` while `mes` column preserves the same date format.

How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: While it *is* possible to have a `Date` class object printed in a format other than `%Y-%m-%d`, it is hard to do, not always general, perhaps a little fragile, and very non-standard. In R, a common theme is the difference between what a data **is** (e.g., `Date` class) and how it is **rendered**. If you want the `Date`-like object for calculations and such, then during calculation you need to allow it to show in the `%Y-%m-%d` format. When you want it rendered in a report, you can then `format(., format="%d/%m/%Y"))`, since at that point numeric-like days is no longer critical.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that your date format is day/month/year. Is this what you are looking for? You should only nee one as.Date() statement.

```
library(dplyr)

testing_df <- data.frame(mes=c('01/02/2021', 
                               '01/01/2021', '01/12/2020', 
                               '01/11/2020', '01/10/2020'))

test_pipeline <- testing_df %>% 
  mutate(mes =  as.Date(mes, format = '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: It returns date class as `%Y-%m-%d`, the idea is that it returns `%d/%m/%Y` while being a date class

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
testing_df$mes <- dmy(testing_df$mes)
```